# How to make a div snap to the side of the tab under a certain width?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a 'news page'-like webpage, and it works perfectly on a  16:9 display, but it struggles with smaller width tabs.
There are 3 solutions I want to test.

1. Making the margin that holds the div away from the left side of the tab exponentially decrease in width
2. Make the margin disappear under a certain width
3. Stop using margins, find another way to keep the div away from the side of the tab and make that disappear under a certain width of the tab.

I don't know if any of these work, but I've seen pages doing this, and I want this feature on my page.
Sadly, I have not found anything like  this on the internet and just got bored. I have not tried anything because of my lack of knowledge about solving this problem.
To demonstrate the issue, my code:(HTML with inline css)

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style= "width:60%; margin-left:20%;">
    <p style="
    margin:0px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin-top:0px;">Praesent semper, leo ac scelerisque 
volutpat, massa ex volutpat dui, in 
suscipit mauris neque auctor quam. 
Vestibulum vel finibus elit.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, if the page is scaled down to a small (around 1000px) width, the 40 % empty space is just too much, so I want to find a way to get rid of that margin and set the width to 100%. I do not want to stick to using margins, so if there is a way to use something else, I'd be really happy.

Things I've tried N°1:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style= "width:60%;  margin: 0 auto; min-width:500px">
    <p style="
    margin:0px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin-top:0px;">Praesent semper, leo ac scelerisque 
volutpat, massa ex volutpat dui, in 
suscipit mauris neque auctor quam. 
Vestibulum vel finibus elit.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

By horizontally centering the div  and adding a minimal width I've

1. Removed margins
2. Made the empty parts disappear under a certain width

But this method still isn't the one I want to use, because if the page is smaller than the value given, you have to scroll sideways to read.

I got help for many people on this site and on other platforms, and solved the problem with flexbox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Oxdan, welcome to SO! For people on SO to help out you will need to post a [reprex] here. Don't expect people to download a Git Repo and install your page.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I've changed it, it might  help a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to read on flex-box

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}
div p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

if this is not what you meant i think you should reframe the question